# Navigate to fragment from bottomsheetdialogfragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation-graph

I want to navigate to `Profile Fragment`, when the user wants to sign up. The `LoginBottomSheetFragment` is responsible to perform this `navigation` whenever it pops up from the bottom and user clicks on the button. The problem is that whenever I am trying to use `findNavController` I get the error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.fjklabs.pkfinance, PID: 8711
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: View android.widget.LinearLayout{32bc1d5 V.E...... ......ID 0,0-1328,935 #7f090188 app:id/rootLayout} does not have a NavController set
        at androidx.navigation.Navigation.findNavController(Navigation.java:84)
        at androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment.findNavController(NavHostFragment.java:118)
        at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentKt.findNavController(Fragment.kt:29)
        at com.fjklabs.pkfinance.fragment.LoginBottomDialogFragment$onCreateView$1.onClick(LoginBottomDialogFragment.kt:42)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

This is the current flow:

```
MainActivity -> Activity A -> Open BottomSheetFragment -> Navigate to Profile Fragment
```

This is what (some part of) my navigation xml looks like:

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    app:startDestination="@id/home">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/login_bottom_sheet"
        android:name="LoginBottomDialogFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_login_bottom_dialog">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/navigate_to_profile"
            app:destination="@id/profile"/>
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/profile"
        android:name="ProfileFragment"
        android:label="Account info"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_profile"/>
</navigation>
```

`BottomSheetDialogFragment`:

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login_bottom_dialog, container, false)
        btnLogin = rootView.findViewById(R.id.signup_user)
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener {
            dismiss()
            findNavController().navigate(LoginBottomDialogFragmentDirections.navigateToProfile())
        }
        root = rootView
        return rootView
    }
```

`Activity A` opens `BottomSheetFragment`:

```
fun showBottomDialogFragment() {
        bottomDialogFragment.show(supportFragmentManager, "LOGIN_DIALOG_FRAGMENT")
    }
```

Since the navigation is part of the `MainActivity` layout, The problem seems like `Activity A` does not have any access to `NavController`. How would get hold of `NavController` in such scenario?

Comment: How are you opening the `BottomSheetFragment`? Where is your `<dialog>` destination?

Comment: @ianhanniballake added details for opening `BottomSheetFragment`. I have an action defined on the `BottomSheetFragment` in the `navigation`, if thats what you meant by `<dialog>` destination?